# Spring Cloud API GATEWAY routing does not working

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I developing new project using Spring Cloud Gateway and microservices. When I run the method with the microservice's own port, the method works. But when I call it with the port of the gateway, the route operation does not occur. Additionally, User Service And Gateway is registered on Eureka Server and used DiscoveryClient annotation

(type=Not Found, status=404).

Gateway YAML file

server:

```
port: 9191 spring: application: name: API-GATEWAYcloud: gateway:  routes:  -id: USER-SERVICE uri: lb://USER-SERVICE/ predicates:-Path=/user/**
```

eureka:

```
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I used yml file for  config. I turned yml file to properties file and problem is solved